# Object.defineProperty, get "this" from within the class, not the "window"

Tags: javascript

In a nutshell, I'm trying to define a variable in the `window` which stays in sync with `myValue` within the class. So `window.myGlobalVarName` should always equal `myValue` within the class.

I'm using `Object.defineProperty` to try to prevent the variable from being re-assigned in the `window`.

However, whenever `get()` is called, `this` is the `window` object, not `this` within the class. Am I missing something obvious here? There's plenty of examples of using `get()` to return values within classes using `this` - what am I doing differently?

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myValue = 1
    this.globalVarName = "myGlobalVarName"
    this.setGlobalObject()
  }

  setGlobalObject() {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      Object.defineProperty(window, this.globalVarName, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get() { return this.myValue } // "this" is actually "window"
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I can resolve this returning the value of a function, but could I be doing this a better way?

```
  setGlobalObject() {
    const getMyValue = () => this.myValue // Return current value of this.myValue
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      Object.defineProperty(window, this.globalVarName, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get() { return getMyValue() } // Returns the actual value from the class
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: But what if there is more than one instance of the class using the same name for the global? The `Object.defineProperty` call will throw. Constructor functions (whether created the old way or via `class`) are primarily for creating factories of similar objects. If you just want a singleton object, you can create it directly instead. (Separately: It's best to avoid globals, which is much easier these days thanks to proper modules, which are supported in modern browsers and by bundlers like Webpack and RollupJS that can create bundles for older browsers.)

Comment: Good observation, in my actual code I have it wrapped in a try/catch, and also check if the variable has been defined already - I just left this out to keep the code example cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, whenever `get()` is called, `this` is the window object, not `this` within the class.

That's how most functions and methods work in JavaScript, `this` is set by how they're *called*, not where they're defined. Details in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Your `get` function is the same, because it's a traditional function (written with method syntax).

To get `this` from where the function is defined, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myValue = 1
    this.globalVarName = "myGlobalVarName"
    this.setGlobalObject()
  }

  setGlobalObject() {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      Object.defineProperty(window, this.globalVarName, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get: () => this.myValue  // ***
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, they *close over* the `this` in the scope where they're defined, exactly as though it were a variable they were closing over. The `setGlobalObject` above is essentially the same as this pre-ES2015 function:

```
// Pre-ES2015 example for comparison
MyClass.prototype.setGlobalObject = function setGlobalObject() {
  var obj = this;                              // ***
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    Object.defineProperty(window, this.globalVarName, {
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: true,
      get: function() { return obj.myValue; }  // ***
    })
  }
};
```

(Arrow functions also don't have their own `arguments` object, `new.target`, or `super`.)

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification and explanation. :)